# oracle convert timestamps to other time masks

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I convert these number columns (timestamp, event_dt) to a date or time mask?
I am trying this:

```
    select to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'), domain_c, to_char(event_date,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'), total_reads from TOP_READ_EVENTS where timestamp= to_char(sysdate-2,'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01481: invalid number format model


SQL> desc top_read_events;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 YEAR                           NUMBER
 QUARTER                        NUMBER
 MONTH                          NUMBER
 DAY                            NUMBER
 HOUR                           NUMBER
 TIMESTAMP                      NUMBER
 DOMAIN_C                       VARCHAR2(255)
 EVENT_DT                       NUMBER
 TOTAL_READS                        NUMBER




select timestamp, domain_c, event_dt, total_reads from TOP_READ_EVENTS where timestamp= to_char(sysdate-2,'yyyymmdd') || '0000'    

 TIMESTAMP DOMAIN_C              EVENT_DT  TOTAL_READS
---------- ------------------------------  ------------ -------------
2.0111E+11 b.e.att-mail.com         2.0111E+11         14406
2.0111E+11 bounce.emailinfo2.bestbuy.com    2.0111E+11         14156
2.0111E+11 bounce.bluestatedigital.com      2.0111E+11         13701
2.0111E+11 plentyoffish.com         2.0111E+11         13384
2.0111E+11 mail.classmates.com          2.0111E+11         13281
2.0111E+11 comcast.net              2.0111E+11         13241
2.0111E+11 uniquelistsmail.com          2.0111E+11         13135
2.0111E+11 tankgorilla.com          2.0111E+11         12835
2.0111E+11 frigidphoenix.com            2.0111E+11         12657
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, *never* store date or timestamp data-types in anything but a date or timestamp column. It causes no end of pain; as you're gathering.

As your "timestamps" have 11 orders of magnitude I'm going to guess that you inserted them in the form `yyyymmddhh24mi`, and that they're not seconds since an unspecified epoch or anything like that.

If you want to convert this then you have to firstly convert them into a character, then into a date. You don't actually need a timestamp as these differ from dates only in fractional seconds.

It'd look something like the following:

```
select to_date(to_char(timestamp),'yyyymmddhh24mi') as my_timestamp
  from top_read_events
```

On a side note *never* call a column timestamp, date, group or another reserved word. It causes too many problems. Personally I normally go for "tstamp" but that's just personal preference.

If you want to convert your "timestamp" into a character you'd then have to convert it into a character again.

```
select to_char(to_date(to_char(timestamp)
                       ,'yyyymmddhh24mi')
              ,'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss') as my_timestamp
  from top_read_events
```

The seconds will always be `00` as you don't have these. Note that I only use *explicit* number to character to date to character conversion. It makes it more obvious to the coders who come after you what you're doing, including yourself 2 years down the line, and there's no chance of the interpreter making a mistake over intention and comparing a number to a character etc.

For this reason I'd definitely change `where timestamp= to_char(sysdate-2,'yyyymmdd') || '0000'`. As you want to date comparison change this into a date and to it that way, i.e.

```
where trunc(to_date(to_char(timestamp),'yyyymmddhh24mi'),'dd') = trunc(sysdate -2)
```

[`trunc()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) truncates this at the day level in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

First off, storing dates and timestamps in columns that are not `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` is poor data modeling.  Life would be much easier if you stored the data in columns with the proper data types.

Second, what format are your numeric columns using to store date and/or timestamp data?  You don't post an example of an actual value-- all we know is that they are 12 digits and begin with 2011.  I'll guess that they are stored in the format YYYYMMDDHH24MI with no seconds-- you'll need to tell us if that guess happens to be incorrect.

Assuming that guess is correct, you would need to convert the number to a string, the string to a date, and then the date back to another string in a different format.  Obviously, this is a bit awkward (and one of the many reasons to store things in the proper data types).  Something like

```
to_char( to_date( to_char( timestamp ), 
                  'YYYYMMDDHH24MI' ),
         'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
```

If your numeric columns are stored differently or there are any cases where data is not stored in the correct format, life gets even less pleasant.